# Cocoa Emacs 24.5 Font Issues Invalid Font Name (Inconsolata-dz)

Tags: macos, emacs, fonts, emacs24

I am trying to set [Inconsolata-dz][1] as my default font to Emacs. Regular Inconsolata works fine, but the dz version is not working properly. Most functions I use keep throwing this error (followed all the instructions online on how to set Emacs font):

`set-face-attribute: Invalid font name: "-*-Inconsolata-dz-normal-normal-normal-*-13-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1"`

I finally got it to work by doing this in my `init.el`:

```
(setq initial-frame-alist '((font . "Inconsolata-dz-13")))
(setq default-frame-alist '((font . "Inconsolata-dz-13")))
```

I also have this in `init.el`, which was generated by `customize-faces`, but it seems to change the font to Helvetica (unless overridden by the code above):

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(custom-safe-themes
   (quote
    ("e16a771a13a202ee6e276d06098bc77f008b73bbac4d526f160faa2d76c1dd0e"
     "d677ef584c6dfc0697901a44b885cc18e206f05114c8a3b7fde674fce6180879"
     "8aebf25556399b58091e533e455dd50a6a9cba958cc4ebb0aab175863c25b9a4"
     default))))

(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :inverse-video nil
             :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil
             :underline nil :slant normal
             :weight normal :height 140 :width normal
             :foundry "nil" :family "Inconsolata-dz")))))
```

Now the issue with the first code above is that doing a `Ctrl+N`, to create a new window will throw the same Invalid font name error.

I installed Inconsolata and Inconsolata-dz the same way on my Mac. Just the regular, default way of installing fonts on OS X.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how I can use Inconsolata-dz properly?

Comment: To see what fonts are available, evaluate the following in a `*Scratch*` buffer:  `(insert (prin1-to-string (x-list-fonts "*")))`  If it is not there, then it's not available.  In general, the original poster should choose one forum or the other, but not cross-post:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16818/cocoa-emacs-24-5-font-issues-inconsolata-dz

Comment: @lawlist I see it there but it is a very long name. When I pasted it into set-face-attribute, (`(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "-*-Inconsolata-g-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1")`), I get 'Invalid face foundry'. Any ideas why? What exactly is the name suppose to be? Inconsolata works but Inconsolata-g and Inconsolata-dz do not work, even though they're all available and installed the same way. I suspect it's the dash in the name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recent versions of emacs seem to have issues with dashes in font names.

This solution fixed it for me:

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16818/cocoa-emacs-24-5-font-issues-inconsolata-dz/29397#29397

Basically had to rename the font to InconsolataDZ.